# The combination of client - client voice chat

Tags: android, p2p, voice

Is it possible voice
conversations between two people
of the Android device without the
server? I ask because I read about
P2P technology and I wonder if I
understand it well, and if the chat is
feasible. I found this article -> http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/ about
sockets, however, do not know if it
something I need it (I am a novice
in communication devices).

Don't
ask for ready code, only answer if
this is possible and whether it
makes sense to implement them.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is possible (as you point) but before you start the chat you'll need some way to retrieve the server IP. I think you need an intermediate server to store your possible android server/clients where from a potential client can pick another user to establish the connection. Does this make sense? Why not? But will work worse than a simple call. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Thrash. I thought of such communication,
because I read that Skype also
used / uses of P2P. However, I do
not know more details, and my
knowledge of P2P is very small. I
would just like to implement a
Skype application but without the
SIP or XMPP.

Comment: Hmmmm, sounds interesting.